# Using different programming language as coworker

Tags: code

I do alot of text file parsing at work and I like to use python since it's a lot of times easier and less code to write but the rest of my coworkers use C# or VB with .net.  People do their own work but should I also start using C# just so in the future coworker/new hire can understand my code?  I asked my boss and he didn't seem to have a strong opinion but he also doesn't do much programming nowdays.

Comment: Does no one else ever review or maintain your code (when you're on holiday for instance) ?

Comment: @mattfreake No, only when someone leaves the company do we look at other people's code

Comment: Is this code part of some shared code base/product, or just your own set of utilities that you develop to assist your work in general?

Comment: Utilities for the company I would say not myself.

Comment: In that case, I recommend migrating your work to whatever language is most commonly used in each context. Your concern about others being able to work with it is valid.

Comment: Don't make more trouble for yourself. Python is not my primary language, nor am I really familiar with Python, but it is a very popular language that most of your new employees are going to be familiar with. So for that reason and for the reason that your boss has no objection, I would keep on doing it that way. If you want to make it easier for your future workers, just create good test suites for your utilities. And if you can, I would even recommend you do TDD.

Answer (score 2):

The job will tell you that. If parsing work gets more complex or becomes parsing projects with coworkers, then someone may have to adapt. It might even be them learning python. Otherwise, keep on working in python and only switch if you think you'd enjoy or benefit from it personally.